# Get part of filename

Tags: bash, variables, parameter-expansion

I try to get the number of the file `num23.txt` by using only one bash variable.

```
User@User-MacBook-Pro:~$ f=num23.txt
User@User-MacBook-Pro:~$ echo $f
num23.txt
User@User-MacBook-Pro:~$ echo ${f%.txt}
num23
User@User-MacBook-Pro:~$ echo ${f/num}
23.txt
User@User-MacBook-Pro:~$ echo ${f/num%.txt}
num23.txt
User@User-MacBook-Pro:~$
```

I try to use only the `%` and `/` operators. How could it change the last command to get as output only `23`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Get the number**

For your particular example (when you have only one substring having only digits):

```
echo ${f//[^0-9]/}
```

or

```
echo ${f//[^[:digit:]]/}
```

**Get the string between prefix and suffix**

But if you want to specify the suffix and the prefix of that string, you have the following alternative:

```
echo `basename ${f/num} .txt`
```

because `echo ${f/num%.txt}` doesn't work properly and Bash doesn't allow you to run something like this `echo ${${f/num}%.txt}`.